# How to auto submit after slide range?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i want to submit form after slide range , How can i do that ?

http://jsfiddle.net/peap/1upb5nd2/1/

HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="">  
<div name = "rangeslider" id="rangeslider" style=" height: 6px; " ></div> 
</form>
```

SCRIPT:

```
$(function(){  
  $('#rangeslider').slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 1000,
    values: [ 90, 290 ],
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
      $('#bottomValue').val(ui.values[0]);
      $('#topValue').val(ui.values[1]);
      $('#rangeval').html(ui.values[0]+" - "+ui.values[1]);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery slider onChange auto submit form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13415041/jquery-slider-onchange-auto-submit-form)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the 'stop' event to sumbit the form once the slider has finished being moved

```
$(function(){  
  $('#rangeslider').slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 1000,
    values: [ 90, 290 ],
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
      $('#bottomValue').val(ui.values[0]);
      $('#topValue').val(ui.values[1]);
      $('#rangeval').html(ui.values[0]+" - "+ui.values[1]);
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      $('form').submit();          
    },
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1upb5nd2/2/